# Use Field Form to modify form Action

Tags: php, forms

i have a form like so that i want to change action depending on the selected value of the form field

Would like the action to be either

http://www.somesite.com/index.php?action=test

or

http://www.somesite.com/index.php?action=test1

```
<form action="http://www.somesite.com/index.php?action=<?php echo $Selected?>" method="post">

      <label for="select">Select:</label>
      <select name="select" id="select">
      <option value="test">TEST</option>
      <option value="test1">TEST1</option>      
      </select>

<input type="Submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
 </form>
```

Comment: You need to use a conditional statement to match against your `$Selected` variable, which is presently undefined, as I'm sure you already knew that ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use onchange event, and change the parameter. Would be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#select').change(function() {
            var param_val = $(this).val();
            var param = "action"; //param in url we want to change
            var href = $('#form1').attr('action');
            var regex = new RegExp("([?;&])" + param + "[^&;]*[;&]?")
            var query = href.replace(regex, "$1").replace(/&$/, '')
            var href = (query.length > 2 ? query + "&" : "?") + param + "=" + param_val
            $('#form1').attr('action', href);
        });
    });
</script>

<form id="form1" action="http://www.somesite.com/index.php?action=test" method="post">
      <label for="select">Select:</label>
      <select name="select" id="select">
      <option value="test">TEST</option>
      <option value="test1">TEST1</option>      
      </select>
<input type="Submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple code, php is server side and cannot change the client side html action after it is sent to the user, so we have to check the selection:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['select'])) {
        if ($_POST['select'] === "test") {
            header("Location: http://www.somesite.com/index.php?action=test");
        } else if ($_POST['select'] === "test1") {
            header("Location: http://www.somesite.com/index.php?action=test1");
        }
    }
?>

<form action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">

  <label for="select">Select:</label>
  <select name="select" id="select" value=>
  <option value="test">TEST</option>
  <option value="test1">TEST1</option>      
  </select>

  <input type="Submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```